# Making one div dictate the height of other divs

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/RGe24/3/  which can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/RGe24/3/show and i want the image to dictate the height of the other divs.For instance,the orange div should stretch to be at the same height as the image div and so should be the middle div.

This is the html

```
<section class="les_head">
    <article class="col-sm-3  les_pink faux_head">
        <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2009/1/23/1232730572620/Isla-Mae-Lubbock-002.jpg" width="100%" />
    </article>

    <article class="col-sm-7 les_pink  main_head">
        <span class="the_name ">Ed,Edd and Eddy - Totally Bonkers </span> 
        <hr/> 
        <span class="the_icons">
            <i class="glyphicon icon-twitter"></i> / 
            <i class="glyphicon icon-facebook"></i> / 
            <i class="glyphicon icon-skype"></i> / 
            <i class="glyphicon icon-google-plus"></i> / 
            <i class="glyphicon icon-dribbble"></i> / 
            <i class="glyphicon  icon-github"></i></span>
    </article>

    <article class="col-sm-2 les_orange les_mail">
        <i class="the_mail glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
        <span class="mail_text">Mail</span>
    </article>
</section>
```

and this is the css

```
.les_pink {
    background-color:pink;
}
.les_orange {
    background-color:orange;
}
.les_head {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.faux_head {
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.faux_head > img {
}
.les_mail {
}
.les_mail > i {
    font-size:40px;
}
.the_mail {
    display:block;
    margin-left:28%;
}
.mail_text {
    margin-left:33%;
}
```

How can i achieve that without padding the orange box towards the bottom?.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNjxx/), the basic concept being that you need to enclose any DIVs you wish to auto size within a wrapper which must have its height defined so its children can calculate what '100%' height is relative to.

```
#wrapper{
    height:200px;
}

.pink, .yellow, img{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
.pink{
    background:pink;

}
.yellow{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
section{
    display:table;
}
section_buttom{
    display:table-row;
}
article {
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    display:table-cell
}
```

please add one div in section button than under place in article and apply this css i think use for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using jQuery to get the height of one element and then set height of other elements to that height. 
Example using your codes classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var new_height = $(".faux_head").height();
  $(".main_head").height(new_height);
  $(".les_mail").height(new_height);
});
```

Comment: Althouht this is an option, I would always prefer pure CSS solutions for simple tasks. Even without JS webpages should work and look just fine, even when 'enhanced' less than with JS.